# Does the Intel C++ Compiler have a resource compiler?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, resources, intel

If so, what's the name of the command line tool to compile resources?

Or an example of use...

I have access to the Professional suite (both Linux and Windows environment but I'm interested mainly in the Windows one), thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a 'resource' to you and how would it have to be compiled?

Comment: Something Microsoft Windows specific?!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Resources are things like bitmaps, icons, cursors, UI strings, dialog box templates, etc., which are added to the executable image.

Comment: if you have Visual Studio installed, you already have it.
Else, you need the Platform SDK. 
There's also a few alternative resource compilers. Like GoRC, Pelles Resource compiler but they all do the same thing.

Comment: Resource compilation does not really belong to the C++ compiler, now does it? It is specific to the resource handling system whether it is an OS API or a code generator.

Answer (score 9):

rc.exe is used to compile resources, and it should be available in the Windows SDK which is free to download.

It doesn't make sense for Intel to provide a resource compiler because resources are just data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm backing up Michael on this. Resources are their own language entirely seperate from C++, and they have their own compiler. I'm not sure why Intel would feel the need to write their own.

Not everything that comes bundled with VisualStudio is part of C++.

The Gnu folks have their own resource compiler (WindRes). I'm guessing the reason for that is that they don't like the license on RC.

Comment: Actually the object file format is identical and the object files generated by windres and RC are interchangeable.

Comment: Hmmm. Did some searching, and you are right Filip. I'll fix that part.